# Serialization with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

can anyone help me out , how to do serialization using jquery?
i tried this script , its not working. But the demo they mentioned is working over there

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-serialize.htm

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works. look here please : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/Z9NeE/)

**And please remember serialize method works only with html form tag**

Comment: yeah, i already got it working same day. i had given wrong jquery file path. Anyways thanks